# Action Bar Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm triying to migrate my app from actionbarsherlock to Google's actionbarcompat, but ActionBarFragmentActivity does not exist. Do I have to use ActionBarActivity or there is another way?

Thanks in advance,
Diego.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look here. This should help you out.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

An Excerpt:

> Extend Activity classes from ActionBarCompat:
>   *ActionBarCompat contains one Activity class which all of your Activity classes should extend: ActionBarActivity.*
>   This class itself extends from FragmentActivity so you can continue to use Fragments in your application. There is not a ActionBarCompat Fragment class that you need to extend, so you should continue using android.support.v4.Fragment as the base class for your Fragments.