# How to change entire layout with fragments?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to change the layout, or inflate the layout, of the main activity to the About activity when one of the items is clicked in the navigation drawer.

This is how my main activity looks

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

            PlaceholderFragment holderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            switch (sectionNumber) {
            case 1:
                bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 05);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new About();
                bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 16);
                break;
            case 3:
                bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 1991);
                break;
            }

            holderFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return holderFragment;

        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

my main activity .xml looks like this

```
<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.projectname.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

I  have a fragment_about.xml
and this is how the about class looks.

```
public class About extends Fragment {

    public About(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

this is how my fragment_main.xml looks like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.projectname.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the navigation drawer works fine but it only changes a text view, i cant figure out how to change the entire layout from the main activity to the about activity on the click of an item in the drawer.

i Just don't know what to do, every time i do something i get an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should extend the FragmentActivity class by your MainActivity. Then in NavigationDrawer click listener do this:

```
RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
About fragment = new About();
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

And remove  from fragment_main (if you not gonna use next like one deeper fragment).

Comment: ActionBarActivity already extends FragmentActivity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18451797/2668136