# android-how to extends FragmentActivity and actionbaractivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using fragments on my activity and also I need actionbar too. 
for having actionbar on android 2.2+, I need to extend actionbar activity and I need to extends FragmentActivity too.

Java doesn't let us to extend two classes.

What is the solution?  How can I do so?

Comment: You can use ActionBarCompat library. Read more here: [Action Bar Fragment Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451575/action-bar-fragment-activity)

Answer (score 32):

If you check source of `ActionBarActivity` you will see that `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. So you only need to extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Thank you. Just to update this answer, now ActionBarActivity has been replaced by AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Even better than the source is the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Answer (score 7):

You can link to the develop website: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

As you look, class `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` ,So you just need to extends `ActionBarActivity`.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                       ↳    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all why you wanna extend both FragmentActivty and ActionBarActivity ?

because **ActionBarActivity** will work for you, and to make your app compatible with lower versions, you should import **android-support-v7-appcompat** in your project

Answer (score -1):

Just Import `ActionbarActivity`. you will find what u want. because `ActionbarActivity` automatically import `FragmentActivity`.

For more details try [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) link

Comment: `ActionbarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html